# Java's java.util.Scanner hangs in PowerShell ISE

Tags: java, powershell

I'm mystified about why this .java program (from Deitel's Java 8 How to Program) hangs where indicated if run with the ISE console, but not if run with the regular PowerShell console. Any ideas or experience with this issue?

```
// Fig. 2.7: Addition.java
// Addition program that inputs two numbers then displays their sum.
import java.util.Scanner; // program uses class Scanner

public class Addition
{
    // main method begins execution of Java application
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // create a Scanner to obtain input from the command window
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number1 = 0; // first number to add
        int number2 = 0; // second number to add
        int sum = 0; // sum of number1 and number2

        System.out.print("Enter first integer: "); // prompt
        number1 = input.nextInt(); // read first number from user *** hangs! ***

        System.out.print("Enter second integer: "); // prompt
        number2 = input.nextInt(); // read second number from user *** hangs! ***

        sum = number1 + number2; // add numbers, then store total in sum

        System.out.printf("Sum is %d%n", sum); // display sum
    } // end method main
} // end class Addition
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Windows PowerShell Integrated Scripting Editor (ISE) does not support console programs that accept user input (aka. interactive applications). For example, try to run `nslookup.exe` from the PowerShell ISE. You will notice that you receive an error message.

> Cannot start "nslookup". Interactive console applications are not supported. 
>   To run the application, use the Start-Process cmdlet or use "Start PowerShell.exe" 
>   from the File menu.
>   To view/modify the list of blocked console applications, use $psUnsupportedConsoleA
>   pplications, or consult online help.
>   At line:0 char:0

[image: PowerShell ISE]

The built-in variable `$psUnsupportedConsoleApplications` controls which executables can or cannot run in PowerShell ISE. This is simply a protective layer, to ensure that the built-in Windows interactive programs are not accidentally executed in PowerShell ISE. You can still run third-party interactive applications, but they will fail, as per your experiences.